# What use is ArrangeIcons in a .Net MDI form

Tags: .net, winforms, mdi

The MdiLayout enumeration has an value called ArrangeIcons. If this is sent to the LayoutMdi method of a MDI parent form then 'All MDI child icons are arranged within the client region of the MDI parent form.'

When I tried putting together a sample MDI form and passing this value into LayoutMdi nothing appeared to happen.

What is an MDI child icon and what is the ArrangeIcons value for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MDI child icon is what you see when the child window is minimised within the parent... get something like the minimising approach of Windows 3.x, with icons appearing to the bottom of the parent forms area.